# Improve Regex To Identify Wordpress Site

Tags: regex, wordpress

So I am writing a little snippet to identify a wordpress site first by regex then will try accessing the login page etc.

Could this be optimized any better? Should I account for blank spaces in between attributes?

```
Regex wordPressPattern = new Regex("(<meta name=\"generator\" content=\"WordPress)| (Powered by <a href=\"http://www.wordpress.org\")+", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: The plus after the closing parenthesis seems misguided. Do you really anticipate multiple matches adjacent to each other (and yet call it a success if there is just one or the other)?

Comment: Left over from a regex I copied and pasted lol thanks for the catch. @tripleee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few improvements:

- Take account for spaces
- Remove the `+` at the end because that doesn't make sense
- Make www. optional
- Make httpS (the S optional)
- What if there is a single quote instead of double quote (which is valid HTML) ? We will use `("|')`
- `name=\"generator\"` I think it isn't relevant so we'll use `.*?` and add `[^>]*>` at the end

To sum it up:

```
(<meta.*?content\s*=\s*(\"|')WordPress[^>]*>)|(Powered\s+by\s+<a\s+href\s*=\s*(\"|')http(s)?://(www.)?wordpress.org(\"|'))
```

Comment: `name=generator` is relevant and specific, you could have `<meta name="description" content="Unlike Wordpress, our blog software has safety plastered on">`